# How to turn multiple dummy vars into 1 factor variable?

Tags: r, dummy-variable

I have a huge data set from a survey with loads of statements that are dummy variables. Each dummy is a factor with levels "quoted" and "not quoted". Since different groups of statements belong to the same topic, I'd like to transform them into 1 bigger factor variable that takes the dummies as levels and the values remain "quoted" and "not quoted" (or 1 and 0, doesn't matter at the moment).

So what I have now looks like this from 2 dummy variables:

```
    pp_plan_thoughtAWhile   pp_plan_justHappen  
     not quoted                  not quoted 
     not quoted                  not quoted 
     not quoted                  not quoted 
     not quoted                  not quoted 
     not quoted                  quoted 
     quoted                      quoted
```

And I need it to look like something like this:

```
               #plan 
      ## value     thoughtAWhile    justHappen
           0           350             550  
           1           650             450
```

Does anyone know how to do this? Any help would be highly appreciated, I'm struggling!

Comment: On the right hand side is the frequency of 0 and 1 right?

Comment: @RanaUsman What do you mean by right hand side here?

Comment: 350, 650, 550 450.

Comment: @RanaUsman Oh yeah, sure! Sorry, didn't realise :)

Answer (score 2):

We can use `gather` to reshape the dataset to 'long' format, then get the frequency with `count` and `spread` to 'wide' format

```
library(tidyverse)
gather(df1) %>%
   count(key, value) %>%
   spread(key, n)
```

Comment: I tried this when I get to count, it throws this error:

Error in .fun(.value[i], ...) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument

Comment: @DanaDaskalova  Are you using the `dplyr::count` or is the function masked from some other library.  Try `gather(df1) %>% dplyr::count(key,value)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do this.

**Data**

```
   pp_plan_thoughtAWhile <-  sample(c("Quoted", "NotQuoted"), 10, replace = T, prob=c(0.7, 0.3))
   pp_plan_justHappen  <- sample(c("Quoted", "NotQuoted"), 10, replace = T, prob=c(0.5, 0.5))
   dv <- data.frame(pp_plan_justHappen, pp_plan_thoughtAWhile)
```

**Some Processing**

```
dv$pp_plan_justHappen <- as.factor (dv$pp_plan_justHappen) 
dv$pp_plan_thoughtAWhile <- as.factor(dv$pp_plan_thoughtAWhile)

library(reshape2)
mdata <- melt(dv)

mdata$bin_plan_justhappen <- ifelse(mdata$pp_plan_justHappen=="Quoted", 1, 0)
mdata$bin_plan_thoughtwhile <- ifelse(mdata$pp_plan_thoughtAWhile=="Quoted", 1, 0)
library(plyr)
table(mdata$bin_plan_justhappen, mdata$bin_plan_thoughtwhile)
plyr::count(mdata, c("bin_plan_justhappen", "bin_plan_thoughtwhile"))
```

**Result**

```
bin_plan_justhappen bin_plan_thoughtwhile freq
               0                     1    2
               1                     0    1
               1                     1    7
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I don't know the exact probabilities, the ones in the example I gave are just for reference, so I don't know how this would work otherwise

Comment: I just generated random data as per your example to work through implementation. You don't need to generate data, it should already scale to your problem.